# ¿Cuales son las meta etiquetas mas recomendadas?

Tags: html, html5, seo

Tengo una duda, cuales son las metas etiquetas mas recomendadas a utilizar para un buen SEO ? o cuales son las principales que no deberían faltar.
y que otras buenas practicas podría tener además de usar las etiquetas de semántica como el section, article, etc.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/fundamentals/seo-starter-guide

Comment: @Yussef Gracias!